# How to reset cumprod when na's are in for pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 2 columns in a dataframe that I want to calculate the cumprod for both, but the cumprod needs to restart once it sees an na in the cell

I have tried using cumprod straightforwardly, but it's not getting me the correct values because the cumprod is continuous and not restarting when the na shows up

Here is an exaple df

```
index     col1     col2
0          2         4
1          6         4
2          1         na
3          2         7
4          na        6
5          na        8
6          5         na
7          8         9 
8          3         2
```

here is my desired output:

```
index     col1     col2
0          2         4
1          12        16
2          12        na
3          24        7
4          na        42
5          na        336
6          5         na
7          40        9 
8          240       18
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that operates on each column and `concats` back together, since the masks are different for each column.

---

```
pd.concat(
  [df[col].groupby(df[col].isnull().cumsum()).cumprod() for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

```
    col1   col2
0    2.0    4.0
1   12.0   16.0
2   12.0    NaN
3   24.0    7.0
4    NaN   42.0
5    NaN  336.0
6    5.0    NaN
7   40.0    9.0
8  120.0   18.0
```

---

A slightly more efficient approach is to calculate the grouper mask all at once and use `zip`

```
m = df.isnull().cumsum()

pd.concat(
  [df[col].groupby(mask).cumprod() for col, mask in zip(df.columns, m.values.T)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar solution with `dict comprehension` and the default constructor

```
pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].groupby(df[c].isna().cumsum()).cumprod() for c in df.columns})
```

---

```
     col1   col2
0    2.0    4.0
1   12.0   16.0
2   12.0    NaN
3   24.0    7.0
4    NaN   42.0
5    NaN  336.0
6    5.0    NaN
7   40.0    9.0
8  120.0   18.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` with `isna` and `cumsum` to get groups to comprod over in each column using `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.isna().cumsum()).cumprod())
```

Output:

```
        col1   col2
index              
0        2.0    4.0
1       12.0   16.0
2       12.0    NaN
3       24.0    7.0
4        NaN   42.0
5        NaN  336.0
6        5.0    NaN
7       40.0    9.0
8      120.0   18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without operating column by column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,4], [6,4], [1,np.nan], [2,7], [np.nan,6], [np.nan,8], [5,np.nan], [8,9], [3,2]], 
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df_cumprod = df.cumprod()
adjust_factor = df_cumprod.fillna(method='ffill').where(df_cumprod.isnull()).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(1)
print(df_cumprod / adjust_factor)

    col1   col2
0    2.0    4.0
1   12.0   16.0
2   12.0    NaN
3   24.0    7.0
4    NaN   42.0
5    NaN  336.0
6    5.0    NaN
7   40.0    9.0
8  120.0   18.0
```